# jQuery: How to apply event handler to $('#text' + 'any integer') without for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, integer

I'm looking for something like this:

```
$('#showcomments' + 'any integer' ).click(function(){ do stuff });
```

I do not want to use a `for` loop because the amount of unique id's `showcomments1`, `showcomments2`, etc. is dependent on a database whose contents change by user input.

And I do not want to access the database in jQuery just to make a `for` loop that always is limited to the amount of rows in the table.

Surely there is some way to express 'any integer'?

Comment: Why not set a class name on the group you want the click event on?

Comment: Any of those `[id^=showcomments]` answers will work **as long as there are no other ID's that begin with "showcomments"**. However, sQVe and Vega are right. A class selector will perform better than the "starts with" selector.

Comment: @Grinn and others: Thanks for your answers; I would still like to know if there is a way to express 'any integer' though, for knowledge's sake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would still like to know if there is a way to express 'any integer'
>   though

Not as far as I know, but you can always filter the selector to exclude letters:

```
$('[id^=showcomments]').filter(function() {
    var numb = this.id.replace('showcomments', ''); //remove text, get integer
    return ((parseFloat(numb) == parseInt(numb)) && !isNaN(numb));//integer check
}).click(function(){ do stuff });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cUVVP/2/)

Comment: A bit complicated but this is most helpful

Answer (score 6):

use the [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector if you don't want to loop

```
$('[id^=showcomments]').click(function(){ do stuff });
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use class selector for such cases...

```
$('.comments').click(function(){ do stuff });
```